# Orientation of a multilinestring

Tags: postgis

I want to calculate the general orientation of a multilinestring, I used this script to compute the orientation of a linestring :

```
ST_Azimuth(  ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(ST_XMax(OSM_geom),ST_YMax(OSM_geom)),2154),432), ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(ST_XMin(OSM_geom),ST_YMin(OSM_geom)),2154),4326)));
```

but I don't know how to generate the global orientation of a multilinestring.

Simple Orientation :

[image: simple orientation :]

Global Orientation :

[image: Global orientation]

Comment: Please **edit** the question to include a more complete description of what you mean by "orientation" and "global orientation" along with a graphic that demonstrates both simple and complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

Pease provide an example of MULTILINESTRING that is not working.

Your statement works fine when I use the following MULTILINESTRING:

```
SELECT ST_Azimuth(
                ST_Transform(
                        ST_SetSRID(
                                ST_Point(
                                        ST_XMax(OSM_geom),
                                        ST_YMax(OSM_geom)),2154),4326),
                ST_Transform(
                        ST_SetSRID(
                                ST_Point(
                                        ST_XMin(OSM_geom),
                                        ST_YMin(OSM_geom)),2154),4326)
                                        )
FROM ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-3.16420835153456 55.9269166007097,-3.164222 55.926918),
(-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001,-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829),
(-3.164339 55.925777,-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001))') as OSM_geom;
```